# Sort a LinkedList of objects by object's variable

Tags: java, list, sorting, object

Here is my problem, I have a `LinkedList` of objects, which have a `String` name and an `int` score value.

Now, I need to sort this list in descending order based on the score value.

How do I do that? I tried with `Collections.sort(List)`, but that doesn't work with objects.

How do I tell Java to use the score as the value to comparison?

Comment: Do you mean you have a ```LinkedHashMap```? LinkedList doesn't have K, V pairs.

Comment: Collections.sort has a version where you can pass comparator. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)

Comment: I don't (?) This will be my first time sorting a List, as previously I was using Arrays, so I'm a newbe. Highschool senior, if that gives any reference how much I know about Java

Comment: Make sure you understand the distinction between ```List```, ```Map``` and ```Set```. What you described is a ```Map```, which contains a *Key* (String name) and a corresponding *Value* (int score).

Comment: @Siddhartha IMO he understand it he has something like `LinkedList<TeamDescription>` where `TeamDescription` is a class with `String` and `int`

Comment: @Siddhartha it could be List of custom objects, we don't know that. He did not show any code. I am guessing from this `LinkedList of objects, which have a String name and a int score value.`

Comment: Ah I stand corrected.

Comment: ^this. My list looks like this:`LinkedList<DopplerBand> DopplerList`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Collections.sort` method accepts a comparator as its second argument.
You can pass in a comparator that defines the ordering that you want.
For example given a `Person` class:

```
class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final int score;

    Person(String name, int score) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", score=" + score +
                '}';
    }
}
```

You can use `Collections.sort` with a custom comparator to sort Persons by descending order of score like this:

```
List<Person> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(new Person("Jack", 3), new Person("Mike", 9)));

System.out.println("before: " + list);

Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Person>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
        return o2.score - o1.score;
    }
});

System.out.println("after: " + list);
```

This will output:

> ```
> before: [Person{name='Jack', score=3}, Person{name='Mike', score=9}]
> after: [Person{name='Mike', score=9}, Person{name='Jack', score=3}]
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Along with other answers, here is a neat Java 8 solution:

```
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparingInt(obj -> obj.score).reversed());
```

The `reversed()` is for descending order, and this compares by `obj.score`.

As noted by Iaune, `obj -> obj.score` can be replaced by `ObjType::getScore` if you are using [Encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)#As_information_hiding_mechanism) correctly.

Comment: Perhaps either obj.getScore() or WhateverTheClassIsCalled::getScore, assuming that the fields aren't public - they shouldn't be ;-). +1 for this neat definition.

Comment: @Downvoter, please leave a comment explaining the issue with my answer so I can fix it.

Comment: Not me, but see my comment.

Answer (score 0):

`Collections.sort(List)` works for `Objects` as long as `Objects` are comparable to one another either through `java.lang.Comparable` or `java.util.Comparator`.Since your `Objects` need custom sorting,you need to implement a comparator

```
Collections.sort(list,new Comparator(){
    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject obj1,MyObject obj2){
        return obj2.score - obj1.score;
    }
});
```