# Sort LinkedList in Java

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I have a List:

```
 LinkedList<Student> student = new LinkedList<Student>();
```

In the Student class, it has an attribute String name. I want to sort the List students by its name.
Is there any way I could do that?

Comment: In alphabetical order?

Comment: Make it implement Comparable or pass a comparable to the sort function

Comment: I think you could look at this one: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33190240/7616247)

Comment: Hello Ryan, 
Welcome to StackOverflow, 
As the commentators suggested, you can search the existing questions which were already answered. If you still think your case is unique, provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply you can use this

```
   student.sort(Comparator.comparing(Student:: getName));//Single Sorting
    student.sort(Comparator.comparing(Student:: getName).reversed());//Single reverse Sorting
    student.sort(Comparator.comparing(Student:: getName).thenComparing(Student::getScore));//Double
```

Answer (score 3):

```
student.sort(Comparator.comparing(Student::getName));
```

Read more about [comparators](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-lambda-comparator-example/).

Answer (score 1):

You can define a Comparator to do this. One easy way is with an anonymous class.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

```
Collections.sort(student, new Comparator<Student>() {
    public int compare(Student a, Student b) {
        return a.getName().compare(b.getName());
    }
};
```

Comment: If you're quoting Java 8, use a lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Collections.sort` method accepts a `comparator` as its second argument. Pass in a `comparator` that defines the ordering that you would like. For example given a `Student` class, you can use `Collections.sort` with a custom `comparator` to sort `Student` by ascending order of name like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

class Student {

    private final String name;
    private final int score;

    Student(String name, int score) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [name=" + name + ", score=" + score + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Student> list = new LinkedList<>(
                Arrays.asList(new Student("David", 3), new Student("Alice", 3), new Student("Thomas", 9)));

        System.out.println("Before Sort: " + list);

        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Student>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
                return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            }
        });

        System.out.println("After Sort: " + list);
    }

}
```

This will produce the output

```
before: [Student [name=David, score=3], Student [name=Alice, score=3], Student [name=Thomas, score=9]]
after: [Student [name=Alice, score=3], Student [name=David, score=3], Student [name=Thomas, score=9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use java > 8. You can use **Lambda expression**, and you get something like this:

`Collections.sort(student, (p1, p2) -> p1.name.compareTo(p2.name));`

or Using sort method in List

`student.sort((p1, p2) -> p1.name.compareTo(p2.name));`